# Symfony EasyAdmin 4 => Collection Field: How to restrict collection elements?

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

Symfony EasyAdmin 4:
I have an entity "Customers" with a OneToMany relation "Addresses". I display these in Easy Admin using CollectionField on the edit page of one customer. The default layout and edit functions will work for me.

The problem: Some addresses (active = false) should not be displayed and should not be editable. I don't really know where to implement this. Does anyone have any advice for me?

Tried to use setQueryBuilder(), but the function is only for EasyAdmin Association Field.

Comment: Do you want to ignore disabled addresses in your whole application -> doctrine filters, if it's only for your collection field -> I don't recall the exact option but you can still modify children form types even if there is a collection field, or you could create a custom field

Comment: I want to ignore disabled adresses in easyadmin crud edit only.